# Multiple definite articles

Tags: articles, possessives

The example:

> "**The/-** managers of **the/-** individual centers will attend the upcoming meeting."

Should I use both definite articles or not when I talk, in this case, about specific managers in charge of their specific departments (they are known to the readers). It seems unnecessary to me to use both articles since it's exactly one-to-one relation.

The word "individual" is meant to say "each". I want it to be clear that only one representative from each center should attend the meeting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further context, it's not really clear what it is that you're wanting to say with "individual". Do you mean **each**?

It could make a difference whether you use the article  or not, as "Managers of individual centers" could be understood to exclude managers of more than one center; that is a less likely interpretation, although not an impossible one, with "Managers of the individual centers".

Any of these phrases would be grammatical:

Center managers...

The center managers...

Managers of centers ...

Managers of the individual centers...

Managers of individual centers ...

The managers of individual centers ...

The managers of the individual centers...

P.S. OP comments:

> I want it to be clear that only one representative from each center should attend the meeting.

In that case you could say:

> The manager of each department...

The use of the definite article there ***The* manager** assumes and indicates that each department has one and only one manager.  If that assumption is not correct, you would say:

> A manager from each department ...

Comment: I have specified the question. Could you check it one more time, please? :-)

Comment: @McFly: Please see the P.S.